# DDD modeling aggregate with few invariants and many fields

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregates

I thinking about modeling aggregates, invariants, data etc. There is common advice to design aggregates to be small. I have problem a with correct splitting domain and simple CRUD.
Let's assume that we have application where we are able to create project and join to it collaborators. There are a lot of informations related with project at the stage of creating (name, description, project_aims, notes, creation date, modified date, collaborators). How to correct design aggregate where there is a rule which check that we can only add 5 collaborators. Taking into consideration that fields name, description, project_aims, notes doesn't really take part in any business rule and there is only requirements that this fields should'nt be empty (those are really invariants?) should those fields really be a part of aggregate?

Is'nt that our real Domain (aggregates, entities, value objects, policies) should hold only data which take part with protecting invariants or help making business decisions?
If so, how to (create) project described above? Should class with all that nonsignificant (from a business point of view) fields be implemented as anemic model outside the Domain and Aggregate root should just have method addCollaborator which protect quantity of collaborators? Is it good idea to save anemic class object using Dao (operates on db table) and for Domain implementation of aggregate, create Repository?

How to add first collaborator during creating project as at the beggining we create anemic class object outside Domain?

Thank you for any help and advice
Papub

Answer (score 1):

> "How to correct design aggregate where there is a rule which check that we can only add 5 collaborators"

`Project` AR most likely maintains a set of collaborators and throws whenever it's size would exceed 5.

> "there is only requirements that this fields should'nt be empty (those are really invariants?)"

Yes, these may be simple rules, but are still are invariants.

> "should hold only data which take part with protecting invariants or help making business decisions"

This can be done when modeling ARs with EventSourcing, where you'd only materialize the properties needed to check invariants on the AR, while having all data in the full set of events.

> "implemented as anemic model outside the Domain and Aggregate root should just have method addCollaborator which protect quantity of collaborators".

You could always attempt to mix CRUD-driven anemia with rich always-valid models, but the anemic/rich model decision is usually consistent for a given Bounded Context (BC), meaning you may have CRUDDy BCs and rich domain model BCs, but rarely both strategies in the same BC.

For instance, perhaps "Project Definition" is a CRUD-driven BC while "Collaboration" isin't. Those BCs may not make any sense, but it's just to give an example.

Furthermore, don't forget DDD tactical patterns are there to allow manage the complexity, they aren't hard rules. If handling a part of your AR through services and another (where there's more meat) with rich behaviors then perhaps that's acceptable. Still, I'd probably prefer CRUDDy behaviors on the ARs themselves like an `update` method rather than giving up in the anemic direction.